# I'd hate to let her down

Tags: will-would

> Alexa's father (Dave): I just hope Principal Trugly doesn't remember
>   me. I was always such a model student. **I'd hate to let her down.**
>
> Alexa's mother: This is about Alexa, Dave.
>
> Alexa's mother: I just don't understand what made you do something
>   like that, Alexa!

Why did Dave use "would" in the sentence above instead of "I hated to let her down."? Is it kind of hypothetical conditional?

I couldn't figure the bold sentence out. I mean I am not sure whether the bold sentence is related to the future or it is the future in the past?

Movie: Alexa and Katie

P.S: Dave was a good boy at school, he doesn’t want the Principal to recognise him and realise that he is in someway “wrong” because he’s Alexa’s dad.

Answer (score 1):

He uses `would` because he's talking about the potential future, not the past. I believe it's an implied conditional:

> [If she recognizes me] I would hate to let her down.

Dave is saying: "I really hope Principal Trugly doesn't recognize me, because I was always a really good student, and if she remembers me, she'll be upset."

Probably because his daughter has just done something naughty, like toilet-papering the principal's house.

Comment: Thank you so much. Shouldn't it be "[If she recognized me not recognizes me ] I would hate to let her down." because it is hypothetical situation and should be demonstrated with past tenses.  And exactly she did "like toilet-papering the principal's house."